# Android: how to create a button with image and text that are both centred

Tags: android, image, layout, button, text

I got stuck in an odd issue with Android - I want to have a button that looks like this:

```
 |-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |                   [icon] <5px> [text text text]                       |
 |-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

and the group ([icon] <5px> [text text text]) should be centred. Note that 5px is used just as a placeholder for any padding you want to have between the icon and the text

I found some answers here that were more or less graviting around either setting a background (which I don't want to do because I have another background) or using the android:drawableLeft property to set the icon.

However looks like the documentation of the setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds method is a bit misleading [(see here)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). It states that the image is placed on the left/right/top/bottom side of the TEXT wich is not true. The icon is placed on the corresponding side of the BUTTON. For example:

Setting the android:drawableLeft property puts the icon on the most left position and gets me this (with gravity CENTER):

```
 |-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | [icon]                     [text text text]                           |
 |-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

or this  (with gravity LEFT):

```
 |-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | [icon] [text text text]                                               |
 |-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Both are ugly as hell :(

I found a workaround that looks like this:

```
public static void applyTextOffset(Button button, int buttonWidth) {
    int textWidth = (int) button.getPaint().measureText(button.getText().toString());
    int padding = (buttonWidth / 2) - ((textWidth / 2) + Constants.ICON_WIDTH  + Constants.ICON_TO_TEXT_PADDING);
    button.setPadding(padding, 0, 0, 0);
    button.setCompoundDrawablePadding(-padding);
}
```

And it works more or less but I don't find it to my liking for following reasons:

- it requires to know the button width. With auto-sized buttons it will not be known until the actual layout is done. Google recommend using a listener to learn the actual width after the rendering is done but this immensely complicates the code.
- I feel like I'm taking over the layout responsibility from the Android layout engine

Isn't there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Hope so you had solved you problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following `Button` subclass to achieve this effect.

1. Paste this class into your project and tweak the package name if desired.

```java
    package com.phillipcalvin.iconbutton;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.TypedArray;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class IconButton extends Button {
      protected int drawableWidth;
      protected DrawablePositions drawablePosition;
      protected int iconPadding;

      // Cached to prevent allocation during onLayout
      Rect bounds;

      private enum DrawablePositions {
        NONE,
        LEFT,
        RIGHT
      }

      public IconButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        bounds = new Rect();
      }

      public IconButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        bounds = new Rect();
      }

      public IconButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        bounds = new Rect();
      }

      public void setIconPadding(int padding) {
        iconPadding = padding;
        requestLayout();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        Paint textPaint = getPaint();
        String text = getText().toString();
        textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

        int textWidth = bounds.width();
        int contentWidth = drawableWidth + iconPadding + textWidth;

        int contentLeft = (int)((getWidth() / 2.0) - (contentWidth / 2.0));
        setCompoundDrawablePadding(-contentLeft + iconPadding);
        switch (drawablePosition) {
        case LEFT:
          setPadding(contentLeft, 0, 0, 0);
          break;
        case RIGHT:
          setPadding(0, 0, contentLeft, 0);
          break;
        default:
          setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom) {
        super.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        if (null != left) {
          drawableWidth = left.getIntrinsicWidth();
          drawablePosition = DrawablePositions.LEFT;
        } else if (null != right) {
          drawableWidth = right.getIntrinsicWidth();
          drawablePosition = DrawablePositions.RIGHT;
        } else {
          drawablePosition = DrawablePositions.NONE;
        }
        requestLayout();
      }
    }
```

2. Modify your layout to use this new subclass instead of plain `Button`:

```xml
    <com.phillipcalvin.iconbutton.IconButton
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
        android:text="@string/search" />
```

3. If you want to add padding between the drawable and the text, add the following to your activity's `onCreate`:

```
    // Anywhere after setContentView(...)
    IconButton button = (IconButton)findViewById(R.id.search);
    button.setIconPadding(10);
```

This subclass also supports `drawableRight`. It does not support more than one drawable.

If you want more features, such as the ability to specify the `iconPadding` directly in your layout XML, I have a [library that supports this.](https://github.com/pnc/IconButton)

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using a custom view to create a custom button.

This could be anywhere from easy to extremely complex.

It would be easy if all you need to do is override `onDraw()`. It will be more complex if you need to lay out multiple views.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it is correct and provides a solution, although I'm not sure I can clasify it as a "more elegant" solution. My point is that it is actually a common sense to expect tha the text and the icon are centred when you call setGravity(CENTER) and creating custom components just for THAT is a bit of an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Simply way is to write Button in LinearLayout. Something like this

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_left"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:text="Button text"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -3):

I tried this in eclipse and it spouted no errors:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    </LinearLayout>
    </Button>
```

Therefore, I suppose you could add an image and text views in a layout, itself inside a button, and center the layout.

Best regards.

Comment: hmmm ... I tried this one but I get a java.lang.ClassCastException when running it on an emulator (2.3.3 compliant)

Comment: Button cannot hold a LinearLayout since it is not a ViewGroup. This can't work.